# Low performance while loading records from another mdb file on Backend

Tags: ms-access

I have a Form in Access that contains a subform. In this Sub form a query should be run and return c.a 2000 records.

I have three query in related this Form but two of the are a little bit complex (I think).

On of these two queries returning records from another `.mdb` file (following query) this form and queries works on i.e `X.mdb` but these query fetch the data from `Y.mdb`

I think it make my form very slow, because if I delete this query it works fine

```
SELECT 
    tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept AS KonzeptID, 
    tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Funktion,
    tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Version, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.ID,
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfad_Kommentar AS Kommentar, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfadname, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfad_CDT, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfad_Kommentar, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.symptombasiert, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Beschreibung_vorhanden, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Status, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Status, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Status,
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Status, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Beschreibung_allgemein, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktionsname        
FROM tb_KonzeptFunktionen RIGHT JOIN qryFunktionen_Übersicht 
    ON tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Funktion = qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktionsname
WHERE (((tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept)=[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]))
```

if I delete this query all of things work fine

And this is another related query assigned to above query (`qryFunktionen_Übersicht`) I added indexes on the fields that I have in **ORDER By** :

```
SELECT tbFunktionen_Übersicht.*, 
    tbFunktionen.Funktionsname, 
    tbFunktionen.Funktionsbeschreibung, 
    tbFunktionen.diagnoserelevant, 
    tbFunktionen.ID AS FunktionsID
FROM tbFunktionen_Übersicht INNER JOIN tbFunktionen 
    ON tbFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktion = tbFunktionen.ID
ORDER BY tbFunktionen.Funktionsname, tbFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfadname;
```

How can I handle my problem, do you have any idea?

Comment: How complex is the query, could you post the SQL? How are you accessing this secondary mdb, do you have linked tables or perhaps opening a connection? Is this secondary mdb file stored locally or on a shared server? When was the last time either database had a compact and repair?

Comment: I edited my Post,I have a linked Table for the first query but the second query is a saved query that the first query use this to run.second  mdb saved on a share server in the same folder of the first mdb. I did compact and repair but no change :(

Comment: Ok.. I'm a little lost now, aliasing your table names would really help to cut down the amount of SQL. Also, basing a query on another saved query stored in a separate mdb sounds like a nightmare and I suspect is the fundamental cause of the slowness. I think it's best if you link in the required tables into the first mdb so you can write one query, although I'm not 100% sure where to start with this, sorry :'(

Answer (score 0):

Please also share information on which fields you added indexes and add information how you named the queries, so we can better understand which query relies on the other one.

In general, for better performance, you can save all queries in your front-end mdb to have the statements already compiled.
SQL JOINs can take a lot of time depending on the amount of data they have to access, so if there's really too much data you want to display this will consume a lot of time and an Access database is not the fastest solution for such tasks.